# Restoring my faith in Gauss Jordan

Tags: linear-algebra

Context: I've taken linear algebra a while ago, and was restudying it. I keep getting stuck on some fundamentals though.

Something I just can't wrap my head around. Consider an $m \times n$ matrix $A$. Let it have some rows, enumerated from $r_1, r_2, ..., r_m$.

Now perform Gauss Jordan Elimination on this matrix. Suppose we find out that there exists a pivot column in each row. That is, none of the rows zero out.

Now, according to Gauss Jordan, this implies that all the rows are linearly independent. This fact puzzles me. How can we be so sure that because of Gauss Jordan's creation of a pivot in the $i$-th row, that that row is independent? In other words, why is Gauss Jordan's discovery of a pivot in the $i$-th row enough to say that $x_1 r_1 + x_2  r_2 + ... = r_i$ cannot exist no matter what linear combination is taken?

Comment: Could you add the field over which you define your matrix?

Comment: I don't really know what a field is... but let's just say it's a matrix of real numbers.

Comment: You should verify that if you replace a set of vectors $r_1,\ldots,r_k$ with the result of performing a single row operation (exchange two vectors, multiply a vector by a nonzero constant, or add a multiple of one vector to another vector), then the resulting vectors $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ are linearly dependent if and only if the original vectors were linearly dependent. This will prove what you want.

Comment: Performing the Gauss-Jordan elementary operations on the rows is equivalent to multiplying your matrix, on the left, by elementary matrices (which are invertible). This does not change the rank of your matrix, and hence, the original matrix has same rank as the reduced one after Gauss-Jordan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix with real entries such that elementary row operations can be applied to $A$ to yield a matrix $B$ in which every row has a pivot. If this is the case, we say that $B$ is *in row echelon form*, and $B$ looks like this:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \dots & 0 & p_1 & * & \dots & * & * & * & \dots & * & * & * & \dots & * & * & * & \dots & * \\ 
0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & p_2 & * & \dots & * & * & * & \dots & * & * & * & \dots & *
\\
0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & p_3 & * & \dots & * & * & * & \dots & *
\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & p_m & * & \dots & *
\end{bmatrix},$$ where $p_i \neq 0$ for all $i$ and the $*$'s represent arbitrary real numbers.

We can apply some more elementary row operations to $B$ to get a matrix $C$ in which the pivots of $C$ are the only non-zero elements in their respective columns. We say that $C$ is *in reduced row echelon form*, and $C$ looks like this:

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \dots & 0 & p_1 & * & \dots & * & 0 & * & \dots & * & 0 & * & \dots & * & 0 & * & \dots & * \\ 
0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & p_2 & * & \dots & * & 0 & * & \dots & * & 0 & * & \dots & *
\\
0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & p_3 & * & \dots & * & 0 & * & \dots & *
\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\\
0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & p_m & * & \dots & *
\end{bmatrix}.$$

How can we conclude from the construction of this matrix $C$ that $A$ has linearly independent rows? Suppose towards a contradiction that there were some nontrivial linear combination of rows of $A$ yielding a row of only $0$'s. It follows that from basic algebra that, for some $k$, we have $$r_k = a_1 r_1 + \dots + a_{k-1} r_{k-1} + a_{k+1} r_{k+1} + \dots + a_m r_n,$$ where not all of the $a_i$'s are $0$. Applying an elementary row operation to $A$, we can obtain a matrix $A'$ in which row $k$ has only $0$'s.

Now, observe that all of the elementary row operations are reversible; that is, if $X$ can be obtained from $Y$ through elementary row operations, then $Y$ can be obtained from $X$ through elementary row operations. So, it follows that $A'$ can obtained from $C$ through elementary row operations. However, there is no way that any matrix obtained from $C$ through elementary row operations can have a row of only $0$'s, since there is nothing in $C$ to cancel out any of the $p_i$'s, since these entries have only $0$'s in their respective columns. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is that

$$a(1,0)+b(0,1)=(a,b)=(0,0) \iff a=b=0$$

which can be extended to

$$x_1 r_1 + x_2  r_2 + \ldots = x_i r_i \iff x_1 r_1 + x_2  r_2 + \ldots - x_ir_i=0 \iff x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_i =0$$

because pivoting itself is obtained by linear combinations of rows.

In other words, indicating with $p_i$ the rows after pivoting we have that $p_i=\sum_j x_jr_j$ and then

$$\sum_i y_i p_i =0 \iff \sum_i z_ir_i=0$$